# Separar primera letra de un string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Necesito poder separar la primera letra de un string y ponerla en un `<span>`. Ejemplo:

```
$string = "Deportes";
```

Y que el resultado sea:

```
<h1><span>D</span>eportes</h1>
```

Puede ser por medio de PHP, JavaScript o jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con el metodo [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

## ejemplo:

```
$string="Deportes";
// seleccionamos de la posicion 1 en adelante
echo substr($string,1);
//eportes
echo "\n";
// seleccionamos de la posiscion 0 a la 1 del string
echo substr($string,0,1); 
//D
echo "\n";
// resultado deseado!
echo "<h1><span>".substr($string,0,1)."</span>".substr($string,1)."</h1>";
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Muchas gracias, me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinion mientras mas carga de trabajo quites de tu servidor mayor eficiencia tendra, por lo tanto te sugiero que es funcionalidad la implementes en javascript jquery

dado el siquiente Codigo obtienes el resultado deseado sin intervencion alguna de los recursos de tu servidor podiendo atender otras llamadas a tu aplicacion.

```js
const str = "Deportes";
const mayuscula = str.substring(0,1);
const resto = str.substring(1);
$("#Mayuscula").text(mayuscula);
$("#resto").text(resto);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span id="Mayuscula"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="resto"></span>
```